# I need help identifying the slope for an equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently having a problem with this

$$2x – 5y = 10$$

I'm supposed to write given equation in slope-intercept form and identify slope. I did that, but I thought the answer was $5$, but it keeps telling me I'm wrong. Then I did it again, and got an answer of $2.5$ but it keeps telling me I'm wrong, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If anyone could help, that would be great. :-)

Comment: The answer is 2/5 = 0.4 ?

Comment: Hint. Can you put that equation in the form $y = ...$?

Comment: @neilroy That's what I was getting, but I must've forgot the 0.4 part.

Comment: Recall that the formula for the slope for a nonvertical line is $y=mx+b$, where $m$ is the slope$ and $b$ is the y-intercept, the part of the line that crosses the y-axis.  The remainder of the variables go to their corresponding coordinates for any number you substitute for either of them first.

Comment: hooneedaalgebra? 2 - 5dy/dx = 0

Comment: If we have a line, then any points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$ on it will satisfy $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=m$ for some constant $m$, which we call the _slope_ of the line.

In particular, any point $(x,y)$ and the point $(0,b)$ will satisfy $\frac{b-y}{0-x}=m\iff y=mx+b$.    

In your case $2x-5y=10\iff y=\frac{2}{5}x-2$, so the $\frac{2}{5}$ must be the slope.

Answer (score 5):

$$5y=2x-10\iff y=\dfrac25x-\dfrac{10}5$$

Compare [with](http://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-1/formulating-linear-equations/writing-linear-equations-using-the-slope-intercept-form) $y=mx+c$

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the slope of a nonvertical line is $y=mx+b$, so do it this way:$$2x-5y=10$$Subtract $2x$ from each side:$$-5y=10-2x$$Rearrange the number and the coefficient of $x$ (count the variable and attach it to the coefficient) on the second side:$$-5y=-2x+10$$Divide each side by the coefficient of $y$, which is $-5$:$$y={2\over5}x-2$$and there you have it!  The slope for the equation is $2\over5$ plus a y-intercept of $-2$.

Comment: The formula for the slope of a non-vertical line through points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ is $$m = \frac{y_1 - y_2}{x_1 - x_2} = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$$  The equation $y = mx + b$, where $m$ is the slope and $b$ is the $y$-intercept, is called the slope-intercept form of the equation of a line.

Answer (score 0):

The slope of a line is a rate of change and is represented by m.

```
  Slope=Vertical change/Horizontal change=Rise/Run
```

When a line passes through the points

$(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$,  the slope is
$m =  \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$

source:http://math.tutorpace.com

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option of using the short cut that Ax + By = C always has a slope of -A/B.